# Check if an imageView is empty

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm trying to check if an imageView is empty because of in the next part of code it uses a force unwrap to work.

if you can, can you try to make it in an if statement like this:

```
if imageview = empty {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check if `UIImageView` `image` property is equal to `nil`

```
if imageView.image == nil {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YourNewImage")
}
```

You can also extend `UIImageView` and create a computed property like `isEmpty` and return true is it is `nil`

```
extension UIImageView {
    var isEmpty: Bool { image == nil }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
if imageView.isEmpty {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YourNewImage")
}
```